# How to move the point to next link?

Tags: compilation-mode

Let's say the compilation error has some filenames with line number

```
blah
blah
src/awesomefile1.c:31
src/awesomefile2.c:152
blah
blah
```

Assume the filename are parsed in the buffer and are links. Now my cursor is at the beginning of the buffer.

I could C-s search `awesome` and get to where I want. But is there a way with less typing?

How can I move the cursor to the next filename/linked text? All I want to is move cursor there and open the file on that line number.

Comment: Have you tried `next-error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tldr;

C-x `

## Details

Picking up the comment from [Vladimir Panteleev](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/6695/vladimir-panteleev) you can find key bindings to `next-error` with

C-h w `next-error`

Further I suggest you bind the command `repeat` to a key (I have `repeat` on C-5) to *quickly* call `next-error` again.